# Grid view formatting of JSON in reactJs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, user-interface

I've a react component in which I need to render the JSON fetched from a 3rd Party API.
The JSON is of the type

```
[
    {
        color: "red",
        value: "#f00"
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        value: "#0f0"
    },
    {
        color: "blue",
        value: "#00f"
    },
    {
        color: "cyan",
        value: "#0ff"
    },
    {
        color: "magenta",
        value: "#f0f"
    },
    {
        color: "yellow",
        value: "#ff0"
    },
    {
        color: "black",
        value: "#000"
    }
]
```

I need to render the JSON fetched in a table of 3 columns.

```
Red     Green     Blue
Cyan    Magenta   Yellow
Black
```

I'm able to render in a single column style but am having trouble with multiple columns.

Is there some way I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the component style like the following.

```js
const data = [
  {
    color: "red",
    value: "#f00"
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    value: "#0f0"
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    value: "#00f"
  },
  {
    color: "cyan",
    value: "#0ff"
  },
  {
    color: "magenta",
    value: "#f0f"
  },
  {
    color: "yellow",
    value: "#ff0"
  },
  {
    color: "black",
    value: "#000"
  }
];

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexWrap: "wrap" }}>
        {data.map(item => (
          <div style={{ flex: 1, flexBasis: "33%" }}>{item.color}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ceyhun Keklik. It worked exactly the way I wanted.